# Python: generator expression vs. yield

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

In Python, is there any difference between creating a generator object through a **generator expression** versus using the **yield** statement?

Using *yield*:

```
def Generator(x, y):
    for i in xrange(x):
        for j in xrange(y):
            yield(i, j)
```

Using *generator expression*:

```
def Generator(x, y):
    return ((i, j) for i in xrange(x) for j in xrange(y))
```

Both functions return generator objects, which produce tuples, e.g. (0,0), (0,1) etc.

Any advantages of one or the other? Thoughts?

Comment: Pick the one that you find most readable.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

There are only slight differences in the two.  You can use the `dis` module to examine this sort of thing for yourself.

**Edit:** My first version decompiled the generator expression created at module-scope in the interactive prompt.  That's slightly different from the OP's version with it used inside a function.  I've modified this to match the actual case in the question.

As you can see below, the "yield" generator (first case) has three extra instructions in the setup, but from the first `FOR_ITER` they differ in only one respect:  the "yield" approach uses a `LOAD_FAST` in place of a `LOAD_DEREF` inside the loop.  The `LOAD_DEREF` is ["rather slower"](http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/python-list@python.org/7844960.html) than `LOAD_FAST`, so it makes the "yield" version slightly faster than the generator expression for large enough values of `x` (the outer loop) because the value of `y` is loaded slightly faster on each pass.  For smaller values of `x` it would be slightly slower because of the extra overhead of the setup code.

It might also be worth pointing out that the generator expression would usually be used inline in the code, rather than wrapping it with the function like that.  That would remove a bit of the setup overhead and keep the generator expression slightly faster for smaller loop values even if `LOAD_FAST` gave the "yield" version an advantage otherwise.

In neither case would the performance difference be enough to justify deciding between one or the other.  Readability counts far more, so use whichever feels most readable for the situation at hand.

```
>>> def Generator(x, y):
...     for i in xrange(x):
...         for j in xrange(y):
...             yield(i, j)
...
>>> dis.dis(Generator)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              54 (to 57)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (xrange)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                40 (to 56)
             16 STORE_FAST               2 (i)

  3          19 SETUP_LOOP              31 (to 53)
             22 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (xrange)
             25 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
             28 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             31 GET_ITER
        >>   32 FOR_ITER                17 (to 52)
             35 STORE_FAST               3 (j)

  4          38 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             41 LOAD_FAST                3 (j)
             44 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             47 YIELD_VALUE
             48 POP_TOP
             49 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           32
        >>   52 POP_BLOCK
        >>   53 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   56 POP_BLOCK
        >>   57 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             60 RETURN_VALUE
>>> def Generator_expr(x, y):
...    return ((i, j) for i in xrange(x) for j in xrange(y))
...
>>> dis.dis(Generator_expr.func_code.co_consts[1])
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              47 (to 50)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    6 FOR_ITER                40 (to 49)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
             12 SETUP_LOOP              31 (to 46)
             15 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (xrange)
             18 LOAD_DEREF               0 (y)
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             24 GET_ITER
        >>   25 FOR_ITER                17 (to 45)
             28 STORE_FAST               2 (j)
             31 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             34 LOAD_FAST                2 (j)
             37 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             40 YIELD_VALUE
             41 POP_TOP
             42 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           25
        >>   45 POP_BLOCK
        >>   46 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
        >>   49 POP_BLOCK
        >>   50 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             53 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Accepted - for the detailed explanation of the difference using dis. Thanks!

Comment: I updated to include a link to a source which claims that `LOAD_DEREF` is "rather slower", so if performance really mattered some real timing with `timeit` would be good.  A theoretical analysis goes only so far.

Comment: Is this still true 13 years later or have latest performance improvements in Python changed that behavior / speed difference?

Comment: @Paebbels A quick check with `dis` shows the same basic difference in Python 3.10.12 as what I showed above.  Whether or not LOAD_DEREF is still (or ever was!) "rather slower" still can be answered only with actual measurement, which can always depend on the host platform (e.g. CPU, OS), and specific version of Python. If it might matter to you you'll need to measure it.

Answer (score 37):

In this example, not really. But `yield` can be used for more complex constructs - [for example](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/08/29/co-routines-as-an-alternative-to-state-machines/) it can accept values from the caller as well and modify the flow as a result. Read [PEP 342](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) for more details (it's an interesting technique worth knowing).

Anyway, the best advice is **use whatever is clearer for your needs**.

P.S. Here's a simple coroutine example from [Dave Beazley](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/index.html):

```
def grep(pattern):
    print "Looking for %s" % pattern
    while True:
        line = (yield)
        if pattern in line:
            print line,

# Example use
if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = grep("python")
    g.next()
    g.send("Yeah, but no, but yeah, but no")
    g.send("A series of tubes")
    g.send("python generators rock!")
```

Comment: +1 for linking to David Beazley.  His presentation on coroutines is the most mindblowing thing I've read in a long time.  Not as useful, maybe, as his presentation on generators, but amazing nonetheless.

Answer (score 19):

There is no difference for the kind of simple loops that you can fit into a generator expression.  However yield can be used to create generators that do much more complex processing.  Here is a simple example for generating the fibonacci sequence:

```
>>> def fibgen():
...    a = b = 1
...    while True:
...        yield a
...        a, b = b, a+b

>>> list(itertools.takewhile((lambda x: x<100), fibgen()))
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```

Comment: +1 that is super cool ... can't say I've ever seen such a short and sweet fib implementation without recursion.

Comment: Deceivingly simple code snippet - I think Fibonacci will be happy seeing it!!

Answer (score 11):

In usage, note a distinction between a generator object vs a generator function.

A generator object is use-once-only, in contrast to a generator function, which can be reused each time you call it again, because it returns a fresh generator object.

Generator expressions are in practice usually used "raw", without wrapping them in a function, and they return a generator object.

E.g.:

```
def range_10_gen_func():
    x = 0
    while x < 10:
        yield x
        x = x + 1

print(list(range_10_gen_func()))
print(list(range_10_gen_func()))
print(list(range_10_gen_func()))
```

which outputs:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Compare with a slightly different usage:

```
range_10_gen = range_10_gen_func()
print(list(range_10_gen))
print(list(range_10_gen))
print(list(range_10_gen))
```

which outputs:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[]
[]
```

And compare with a generator expression:

```
range_10_gen_expr = (x for x in range(10))
print(list(range_10_gen_expr))
print(list(range_10_gen_expr))
print(list(range_10_gen_expr))
```

which also outputs:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[]
[]
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `yield` is nice if the expression is more complicated than just nested loops. Among other things you can return a special first or special last value. Consider:

```
def Generator(x):
  for i in xrange(x):
    yield(i)
  yield(None)
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes there is a difference.

For the generator expression `(x for var in expr)`, `iter(expr)` is called when the expression is **created**.

When using `def` and `yield` to create a generator, as in:

```
def my_generator():
    for var in expr:
        yield x

g = my_generator()
```

`iter(expr)` is not yet called.  It will be called only when iterating on `g` (and might not be called at all).

Taking this iterator as an example:

```
from __future__ import print_function


class CountDown(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        print("ITER")
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n == 0:
            raise StopIteration()
        self.n -= 1
        return self.n

    next = __next__  # for python2
```

This code:

```
g1 = (i ** 2 for i in CountDown(3))  # immediately prints "ITER"
print("Go!")
for x in g1:
    print(x)
```

while:

```
def my_generator():
    for i in CountDown(3):
        yield i ** 2


g2 = my_generator()
print("Go!")
for x in g2:  # "ITER" is only printed here
    print(x)
```

Since most iterators do not do a lot of stuff in `__iter__`, it is easy to miss this behavior.  A real world example would be Django's `QuerySet`, which [fetch data in `__iter__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.1/django/db/models/query.py#L235) and `data = (f(x) for x in qs)` might take a lot of time, while `def g(): for x in qs: yield f(x)` followed by `data=g()` would return immediately.

For more info and the formal definition refer to [PEP 289 -- Generator Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Answer (score 5):

When thinking about iterators, the `itertools` module:

> ... standardizes a core set of fast, memory efficient tools that are useful by themselves or in combination. Together, they form an “iterator algebra” making it possible to construct specialized tools succinctly and efficiently in pure Python.

For performance, consider [`itertools.product(*iterables[, repeat])`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

> Cartesian product of input iterables.
>
> Equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example, `product(A, B)` returns the same as `((x,y) for x in A for y in B)`.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> def gen(x,y):
...     return itertools.product(xrange(x),xrange(y))
... 
>>> [t for t in gen(3,2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference that could be important in some contexts that hasn't been pointed out yet. Using `yield` prevents you from using `return` for something else than [implicitly raising StopIteration (and coroutines related stuff)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595895/return-and-yield-in-the-same-function).

This means this code is ill-formed (and feeding it to an interpreter will give you an `AttributeError`):

```
class Tea:

    """With a cloud of milk, please"""

    def __init__(self, temperature):
        self.temperature = temperature

def mary_poppins_purse(tea_time=False):
    """I would like to make one thing clear: I never explain anything."""
    if tea_time:
        return Tea(355)
    else:
        for item in ['lamp', 'mirror', 'coat rack', 'tape measure', 'ficus']:
            yield item

print(mary_poppins_purse(True).temperature)
```

On the other hand, this code works like a charm:

```
class Tea:

    """With a cloud of milk, please"""

    def __init__(self, temperature):
        self.temperature = temperature

def mary_poppins_purse(tea_time=False):
    """I would like to make one thing clear: I never explain anything."""
    if tea_time:
        return Tea(355)
    else:
        return (item for item in ['lamp', 'mirror', 'coat rack',
                                  'tape measure', 'ficus'])

print(mary_poppins_purse(True).temperature)
```