# Return list from generator Python

Tags: python, networkx, yield

I'm trying to make a customize version for DFS from the original version of networkx. You can relate to the original version of DFS from networkx here: [networkx DFS](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/_modules/networkx/algorithms/traversal/depth_first_search.html)

In my implementation, I want to add a child which contain "if" in the label to a list and return the list after all but I can't make it

```
def extract_expression(label):
    m = re.search('if(.+?)goto', label)
    if m:
       return m.group(1)
    return None

def dfs_edges(G, source=None):  
    path = list()
    if source is None:
        nodes = G
    else:
        nodes = [source]
    visited=set()
    for start in nodes:
        if start in visited:
            continue
        visited.add(start)
        stack = [(start,iter(G[start]))]
        while stack:
            parent,children = stack[-1]
            try:
                child = next(children)
                label = G.node[child]['label']
                if "if" in label:
                    print child
                    # print extract_expression(label)
                exp = extract_expression(label)
                path.append(exp)
                if child not in visited:
                    yield parent,child      
                    visited.add(child)
                    stack.append((child,iter(G[child])))
            except StopIteration:
                stack.pop()
    return path
```

Throw the error

```
    return path
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator
```

Comment: A generator returns items one by one with `yield`. No `return`.

Comment: what extract_expression does.

Comment: @JayParikh: it just a function to extract substring from the original string for my work

Comment: You cannot have a `return` in a generator, as it says.  If you want to add to a list then start with an empty one and just `append()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return and yield in the same function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595895/return-and-yield-in-the-same-function)

Comment: @cdarke : i don't get you, i started with an empty list in the beginning and append it, still can't get the result

Comment: Why don't you `yield parent, child, path`. `return` in a generator may only be used to `return None`

Comment: @Chris_Rands there are many possibles duplicate for this question for sure, I searched for it, but my case is different from the others

Comment: Why marked down?, this is not something possible duplicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generator function must always **yield** its result.

You could simply replace the `return path` with `yield path` but that would be bad practice and overall inconsistent. 
You'd return the `parent, child` and at one time suddenly get a list.

Comment: yes, is there any other way to modified this code? , because I just want to return the list

Comment: Yes, simply remove the `yield parent, child` statement and keep your `return path` at the end. :)