# Why do I still receive a generator even if I don't hit yield keyword in function

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

```
def get_data(batchsize=None):
    conn = psycopg2.connect('database parameter')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = 'select * from table'
    cursor.execute(query)
    if not batchsize:
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        return result
    else:
        while True:
            result = cursor.fetchmany(batchsize)
            if not result:
                break
            yield result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = get_data()
```

In above function type of data should have been a list as argument batchsize=None.
but this function is returning generator in both cases.
If I comment else part of the function then it's returning a list.

Comment: Alright, so what's the question here? And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want this function to return a list when batchsize=None and a generator when batchsize is not None. but right now I'm getting generator only for both cases. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I got what you're asking about. You're asking:

> Why do I still receive a generator even if I don't hit `yield` keyword in `get_data()`?

The thing is that a function, which contains at least one `yield` statement is a generator. So your `get_data()` **function is a generator**. Because of that you always receive a generator object out of `get_data()`.

The meaning of `return` in a generator is a bit different from ordinary function. In a generator any `return x` statement is equivalent to `raise StopIteration(x)`.

And when you comment out part with `else`, you comment out `yield` statement, so `get_data()` becomes an ordinary function. Therefore it returns a `list` as you expect.

Related SO post: [Return and yield in the same function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595895/return-and-yield-in-the-same-function)

Comment: Yeah, you got it spot on and thanks for the explanation.
*updating the question*