# Scrapy/Python yield and continue processing possible?

Tags: python, scrapy, return, yield

I am trying this sample code

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider, Request  
import scrapy

class MySpider(Spider):

    name = 'toscrapecom'
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html']

    urls = (
        'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{}.html'.format(i + 1) for i in range(50)
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in self.urls:
            return Request(url)
```

It crawls all the pages fine. However if I yield an item before the `for` loop then it crawls only the first page. (as shown below)

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider, Request  
import scrapy

class MySpider(Spider):

    name = 'toscrapecom'
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html']

    urls = (
        'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{}.html'.format(i + 1) for i in range(50)
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.item.Item()
        for url in self.urls:
            return Request(url)
```

But I can use `yield Request(url)` instead of `return...` and it scrapes the pages backwards from last page to first.

I would like to understand why `return` does not work anymore once an `item` is yielded? Can somebody explain this in a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

You ask why the second code does not work, but I don’t think you fully understand why the first code works :)

The `for` loop of your first code *only loops once*.

What is happening is:

1. `self.parse()` is called for the URL in `self.start_urls`.
2. `self.parse()` gets the first (and only the first!) URL from `self.urls`, and returns it, exiting `self.parse()`.
3. When a response for that first URL arrives, `self.parse()` gets called again, and this time it returns a request (only 1 request!) for the second URL from `self.urls`, because the previous call to `self.parse()` already consumed the first URL from it (`self.urls` is an [iterator](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp)).

The last step repeats in a loop, but it is not the `for` loop that does it.

You can change your original code to this and it will work the same way:

```py
def parse(self, response):
    try:
        return next(self.urls)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Comment: Your explanation is very detailed but it still does not explain why `yield` stops execution. Shouldn't it return a `return Request(url)` which will in return reach for loop again? Why it stops in first iteration? As far as I understand, yield does raise `StopIteration`?

Answer (score 0):

Because to call items/requests it should be *generator* function. 
You even cannot use `yield` and `return` in the same function with the same "meaning", it will raise `SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator`.

The `return` is (almost) equivalent to raising StopIteration. In this topic [Return and yield in the same function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595895/return-and-yield-in-the-same-function) you can find very detailed explanation, with links specification.

Comment: It is not clear to me why my problem should be with `return` raising `StopIteration` as the method works normally, unless I use `yield`. So if the problem was due to `StopIteration` exception then shouldn't the first example crawl only first url and stop?