# Generator function not returning or printing anything

Tags: python

Was giving [Sieve of Eratosthenes - Finding Primes Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939660/sieve-of-eratosthenes-finding-primes-python) first answer's code a try but unable to return or print any value.

Only output is "generator object sieve at..."

Solutions I found were creating a list of the values and returning that but still nothing.

How can I get this code to return / print a list of primes?

```
def sieve(limit):
  count = [False] * 2 + [True] * limit-2

  for (num, prime) in enumerate(count):
    if prime:
      yield num

      for ind in range(num*num, limit, num):
        count[ind] = False

  primes = [i for i in count if count[i]]

  return primes



print(sieve(10))
```

Comment: You cant yield and return at the same time...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return and yield in the same function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595895/return-and-yield-in-the-same-function)