# Duplicate each member in an iterator

Tags: python, iterator

Given an iterator `i`, I want an iterator that yields each element `n` times, i.e., the equivalent of this function

```
def duplicate(i, n):
    for x in i:
        for k in range(n):
            yield x
```

Is there an one-liner for this?

Related question: [duplicate each member in a list - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449077/duplicate-each-member-in-a-list-python), but the `zip` solution doesn't work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my simple solution, if you want to duplicate each element same times. It returns a generator expression, which should be memory efficient.

```
def duplicate(i, n):
    return (k for k in i for j in range(n))
```

An example usage could be,

```
print (list(duplicate(range(1, 10), 3)))
```

Which prints,

> [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8,
>   8, 9, 9, 9]

Comment: "which _is_ memory efficient", actually _more_ memory efficient then generator functions since the expression doesn't need the same kind of python namespace.

Comment: What is generator function?

Comment: function with `yield` statement like in OP

Comment: oh I may be wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995418/python-generator-expression-vs-yield

Answer (score 4):

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip(*itertools.tee(source, n)))
```

Example:

```
>>> x = (a**2 for a in xrange(5))
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip(*itertools.tee(x, 3))))
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 9, 16, 16, 16]
```

Another way:

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(item, n) for item in source)

>>> x = (a**2 for a in xrange(5))
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(item, 3) for item in x))
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 9, 16, 16, 16]
```

Comment: Don't star the argument to `itertools.chain()`.  Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` instead.

Comment: Is this the same thing? I mean, according to the function in question, he call call `duplicate` function multiple time with a different number for each element.

Comment: Thanks for the `tee` recipe!  The docs say "This (`tee`) itertool may require significant auxiliary storage", but in this actual use case it seems okay?  Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @TonyBetaLambda: As described in the docs, `tee` will use a lot of storage if you use a lot of one of the duplicates while not using the others.  In this example that is not a concern because all duplicates are advanced in sync (i.e., you get the first element from all of them before getting the second from any of them).

Answer (score 1):

Use a generator expression:

```
>>> x = (n for n in range(4))
>>> i = (v for v in x for _ in range(3))
>>> list(i)
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```