# How to get Cartesian product of two iterables when one of them is infinite

Tags: python, python-itertools, cartesian-product

Let's say I have two iterables, one finite and one infinite:

```
import itertools

teams = ['A', 'B', 'C']
steps = itertools.count(0, 100)
```

I was wondering if I can avoid the nested for loop and use one of the infinite iterators from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module like `cycle` or `repeat` to get the Cartesian product of these iterables.

**The loop should be infinite because the stop value for `steps` is unknown upfront.**

Expected output:

```
$ python3 test.py  
A 0
B 0
C 0
A 100
B 100
C 100
A 200
B 200
C 200
etc...
```

Working code with nested loops:

```
from itertools import count, cycle, repeat

STEP = 100 
LIMIT = 500
TEAMS = ['A', 'B', 'C']


def test01():
    for step in count(0, STEP):
        for team in TEAMS:
            print(team, step)
        if step >= LIMIT:  # Limit for testing
            break

test01()
```

Comment: Can you clarify how you know when to break out of your infinite loop?

Comment: Sure, the "step" (offset) is used to make API calls for different teams in the URL simultaneously, once the value in the payload indicates  there is no "next" URL, loop is skipped for specific team and if that's the case for all teams the code breaks the loop. This is a workaround to make the requests in parallel using asyncio otherwise each request would have to wait for the next URL from the payload causing to run sequentially.

Comment: Related: [Does itertools.product evaluate its arguments lazily?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45586863/7851470)

Comment: @Georgy Your edit is good but the accepted answer only works with finite iterable. This question was answered for finite iterable, if the issue with infinite iterable is needed, another question should be asked. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332827/6251742

Comment: @DorianTurba I don't see how it is a "chameleon question". IIUC, the first version of the question already had a requirement for an infinite iterator, though, it was not stated clearly enough. OP's edit (revision #3) just made it explicit. IMHO the rollbacks that followed after were wrong.

Comment: @Georgy I know. But the OP accept an answer that doesn't solve anything in  infinite loop. I'm ok if it's more explicit now, but by doing it, the accepted answer is not wrong. This is what bother me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product
for i, j in product(range(0, 501, 100), 'ABC'):
    print(j, i)
```

As the docs say `product(A, B)` is equivalent to `((x,y) for x in A for y in B)`. 
As you can see, `product` yield a tuple, which mean it's a generator and do not create a list in memory in order to work properly.

> This function is roughly equivalent to the following code, except that the actual implementation does not build up intermediate results in memory:
>
> ```
> def product(*args, **kwds):
>     # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
>     # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
>     pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
>     result = [[]]
>     for pool in pools:
>         result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
>     for prod in result:
>         yield tuple(prod)
> ```

But you can't use `itertools.product` for infinite loop due to a [known issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue10109):

> According to the documentation, itertools.product is equivalent to
>   nested for-loops in a generator expression. But,
>   itertools.product(itertools.count(2010)) is not.
>
> ```
> >>> import itertools
> >>> (year for year in itertools.count(2010))
> <generator object <genexpr> at 0x026367D8>
> >>> itertools.product(itertools.count(2010))
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> MemoryError
> ```
>
> The input to itertools.product must be a finite sequence of finite
>   iterables.

For infinite loop, you can use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60166626/6251742).

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to do it without nested loops. Based on [this answer on *Duplicate each member in an iterator*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36002647/7851470) you could write this:

```
from itertools import count, chain, cycle, tee 

teams = ['A', 'B', 'C']
steps = count(0, 100)

for team, step in zip(cycle(teams), chain.from_iterable(zip(*tee(steps, len(teams))))):
    if step == 300:
        break
    print(team, step)
```

which will give the expected output:

```
A 0
B 0
C 0
A 100
B 100
C 100
A 200
B 200
C 200
```

It does the job but it's much less readable, though.