# Difference between different generators, "yield" and returning tuple iteration in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

What is the proper difference between doing *`yield i` from an iteration* and *`return (i for i in range(10))`.*

```py
def generator1():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

def generator2():
    return (i for i in range(10))
```

For example, see these functions `generator1()` and `generator2()` both are differently written but both return a generator.

*Outputs of IDLE:-*

```py
>>> generator1()
>>> <generator object generator1 at 0x107870468>

>>> generator2()
>>> <generator object generator2.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x107870db0>

>>> import sys

>>> sys.getsizeof(generator1())
>>> 88
>>> sys.getsizeof(generator2())
>>> 88
```

---

As we can tell `generator2()` has fewer LOC (line of code) than `generator2` and also the size of the object is the same, I've some questions.

- What is the difference between both functions?
- What does `<genexpr>` means when printing `generator2()`?
- Which is the more suitable and efficient way of creating a generator?

Comment: Interesting question, but the title of your question doesn't quite make sense. `(i for i in range(10))` is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), not a "tuple iteration".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: generator expression vs. yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995418/python-generator-expression-vs-yield)

Comment: @JohnColeman: Sorry, I don't know what can be the exact title to this question. if we do `return tuple(i for i in range(10))` then it is tuple iteration.

Comment: No, in this case you just return a tuple, which was instantiated from a generator.

Comment: But if you introduce `tuple()` like that you are fundamentally modifying the function is such a way that it would no longer be similar to the first one. Don't get hung up on the round brackets in generator expressions. They have nothing to do with tuples.

Comment: `<genexpr>` means [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression)

Comment: Obviously, the simplest and best expression in this case would just be `range(10)`. All the "decorations" around it may make some point, but only lose efficiency. Of course, this is assuming a recent version of Python.

Comment: @Amitai `range` is just a dummy iteratable. If you wanted something a little more juicy, you could do for example, `math.sqrt(i) for i in range(0, 10)`

Comment: @wjandrea - agreed (obviously). However, seeing `(i for i in range(10))` being discussed, without mention that it is actually equivalent to `range(10)`, just with extra steps, prompted me to comment as I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is where the generator is defined.  generator1 is a special generator function, because it contains a `yield` statement.  generator functions always return generators.  The generator is defined when you invoke generator1. 
 generator2 is a regular function that uses a generator expression to construct a generator, and then returns it.  The generator is defined when the line `(i for i in range(10))` is executed. But if you add more logic, generator2 can return anything else, like None.  For example:

```
def generator2(do_generator):
    if do_generator:
        return (i for i in range(10))
    else:
        return "I quit"
```

You can't do anything like that with generator1.  It cannot return anything except a generator.

`<genexpr>` is short for *generator expression*.  In your case, that's `(i for i in range(10))`.  Generator expressions are very similar to list comprehensions, but they produce generators rather than lists.